# Как выбрать option в select по тексту option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как выбрать `<option>` в `#ComboBox` по тексту `<option>`: *"Text 1"*, *"Text 2"*, *"Text 3"*?

```
<select id="ComboBox" >
    <option value="1">Text 1</option>
    <option value="2">Text 2</option>
    <option value="3">Text 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что нужно выбрать `<option>` в зависимости от его содержимого?

Comment: да, то есть выбрать строчку, задав, например, "Text 1"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery позволяет находить элемент по содержанию так:

```
$("option:contains('Text 1')").attr('selected', true)
```

Comment: спасибо, работает!

Comment: Для булевых атрибутов, таких как selected, disabled, checked и пр. в jquery настоятельно рекомендуют использовать .prop('someProp', true) вместо атрибутов.  Из документации: "The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations..."